# How do I keep an application running after exiting it?

Tags: android

I wrote an application that has 2 activities: one activity is the main activity and the other will be called by the main through an Intent. In the main activity I will connect to an Arduino board through Bluetooth. However, I want the connection to continue when I call the sub activity, but it disconnects when I push the button of the phone to escape the application (wherever in the main or sub activity) and go to the applications screen of the phone. So, please give me some ideas.

The main activity:

```
public class BackgroundActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "00:06:66:43:9B:57";

    private Button Living_Room;
    private Intent  L_intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Amarino.connect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);// CONNECT TO ARDUINO BOARD 

        Living_Room = (Button) findViewById(R.id.living);
        Living_Room.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Living_Room.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                L_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LivingRoom.class);
                startActivityForResult(L_intent, 0);
            }

        });
    }

   @Override
    protected void onStop(){

        super.onStop();
        //Amarino.disconnect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want to be able to run your "sub activity" while your application is not in the foreground.. This is what Android Service is for! So try changing your "sub activity" to a service.

Check it out here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
It's similar to an Activity, but it runs in the background and doesn't have a GUI.